# Will my indoor Michelia alba thrive in a self-watering container?

Tags: houseplants, containers

I have a [Michelia alba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia_%C3%97_alba) plant and I am considering purchasing a large self-watering container for it.

I've read a lot about drying out roots between watering, so I was wondering if a self watering container is a bad idea.